# Connect to MFA server(radius) over Public IP

Tags: azure, radius, multi-factor-authentication

I have an MFA Server running on a VM in my Azure Cloud. The MFA server is using AD as a backend. I am using the MFA built-in radius.

When I connect to the VM, I test the radius server on the LAN IP 10.0.0.6 with NTradPing it works great I connect to the radius server it sends me a phone call I authorize it and it checks the backend to make sure my credentials are OK.

My VM also has a public IP and I have turned off the firewall on the VM and allowed port 1812 to be open in the network security group for the VM.

When use nmap from my laptop on the public IP it says the port is open:

> $ sudo nmap -Pn -sU -p 1812 'ip removed'
>
> Starting Nmap 6.40 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2018-07-11 09:22 CDT Nmap
>   scan report for 'ip removed' Host is up. PORT     STATE
>   SERVICE 1812/udp open|filtered radius
>
> Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 2.07 seconds

When I run radtest (linux command line) I get no response back and no phone call to my phone.

Any ideas?

PS- I have also made clients with the correct IP's on the MFA/Radius server.

Comment: what authentication method are you using, what RADIUS server are you using, do you have any custom logic?

Comment: have you tried taking a tcpdump on the radius server to see if the UDP datagram is reaching the destination or not?